# SQL Azure impersonation error when called from Azure Function App's Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-functions

## The scenario

I have an Azure Functions App that will be triggered when a file is added to a blob storage. It will be triggered once per day.

That app will call a stored proc in a SQL Azure Database, connecting using the Function App's Managed Service Identity. That stored proc has the `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` clause, and it will bulk insert the added file to the database.

Note: The database user for the managed identity was created and granted permission to execute the stored proc in question.

## The problem

The stored proc call will fail by default, with error message (full stack trace below):

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

If I login to the database in SQL Management Studio using the admin user id and simply do a `EXECUTE AS USER = '...'` statement, then re-triggered the Functions App soon after, the next stored proc call from the Functions App will be successful.

It seems as though I need to manually "refresh" something in the database to allow the stored proc call from the Functions App to be able to impersonate successfully.

Note: The managed service identity normally works when calling the database. It seems to just having issues with database user impersonation.

## The question

How can I fix this if I want to call the stored proc using the Managed Service Identity?

## The exception stack trace

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: OnFileAddedToInbox
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean isInternal, String endMethod)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at AzureFunc.OnFileAddedToInbox.Run(CloudBlockBlob blob, String fileName, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 585
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 532
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, IFunctionOutputDefinition outputDefinition, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 468
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 278
ClientConnectionId:712b8ea4-c8e9-4701-aed1-643b16b111d9
Error Number:15517,State:1,Class:16
ClientConnectionId before routing:d9545837-a804-4a42-8e84-12d5edac5f17
Routing Destination:***.database.windows.net,11069
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 322
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 117
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the [Managed Identity needs to have a user created with same name to access the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) via a SQL script.

Try running

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

And grate the user the appropriate access.

One call out that isn't well documented is if your Azure Function is deleted and recreated the script will need to be ran again since it will have a different thumbprint.  Azure SQL DBs is one of the few resources that will require the access to be reassigned like this for Managed Identities.

Comment: It was able to intermittently connect to the database in the first place was because I had already created the db user for the app's managed identity and grant permission to execute the stored proc.